# Configure NFS server for PersistentVolume either via DNS or static ClusterIP

Tags: kubernetes, nfs, google-kubernetes-engine, kube-dns

I have a kubernetes cluster running on google container engine that defines a Pod running a NFS-Server, which I want to access in other Pods via various `PersistentVolume`s.

What is the best way to configure the NFS Service, if it is in the same cluster?

According to various documentation ive found its not possible to rely on kube-dns for this, because the node starting the kubernetes pod is not configured to use it as its DNS.

So this is out of question (and really does not work - ive tested it, with various different hostname/FQDN...)

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: xxx-persistent-storage
  labels:
    app: xxx
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  nfs:
    path: "/exports/xxx"
    server: nfs-service.default.svc.cluster.local  # <-- does not work
```

I can start the NFS Server and check its ClusterIP via `kubectl describe svc nfs-service` and then hardcode its Endpoint-IP for the PV (this works):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: xxx-persistent-storage
  labels:
    app: xxx
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  nfs:
    path: "/exports/xxx"
    server: 10.2.1.7  # <-- does work
```

But this feels wrong - as soon as I need to recreate the NFS-Service ill get a new IP and i have to reconfigure all the PVs based on it.

- What is the best-practice here? Im surprised i did not find any example for it, because i supposed thats quite a normal thing to do - isnt it?
- Is it possible to set a kind of static IP for a service, so that i can rely on having always the same IP for the NFS service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. To make sure that your Service is using a static IP just add `clusterIP: 1.2.3.3` under the `spec:` section of the Service.

From the canonical [example](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/examples/volumes/nfs/README.md):

> In the future, we'll be able to tie these together using the service names, but for now, you have to hardcode the IP.

Comment: Thank you - i was hoping I made something wrong and there is a more nicer solution available. Dont like the idea of the hardcoded IP, if I want to easily reuse the definition file between prod and testing for example